# ApplicationClose event

Tags: windows-runtime, win-universal-app

I'm developing Windows 10 universal app in C#/XAML.

I want to implement such a policy, that whenever user closes my app (and some other conditions are met, but its irrelevent here) an adverisment will display.

My question is how can I intercept and cancel/handle an event when application is being closed? This is easy when user decides to close the app by for example pressing a button that I'll define in XAML, but what if he presses Alt+F4? In Winforms this is easy as well:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.FormClosing += Form1_FormClosing;
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
```

But how can I achieve similiar effect in in Windows 10 universal app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can not achieve the similar effect in Windows 10 Universal App (and Windows 8.1 Store App), because in the modern app, the user have the full control of the app and the app can not stop the user closing a app.

If you have sth need to handle when user closing the application, as Lukkha stated, you can handle them in Application.Suspending, but there is a time limitation by default, all of the things should be done within 5s. If you want to have more than 5s, you need to request a ExtendedExecutionSession.

[Using Extended Execution in Windows 10 Universal Apps](http://dailydotnettips.com/2015/07/15/using-extended-execution-in-windows-10-universal-apps/)

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid there is no option to cancel the closing of the app or even delay it. The Suspending event is the only indication your app will receive prior to termination (if it happens). Check out the `Application.Suspending` event: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.ui.xaml.application.suspending.aspx